# making Graphs for VBA, with different kind of data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an assignment for my school exam project and i have tried and tried and hope u can help me

The question is like this:

As "delayed" students constitute a "risk" for the university, it is important for the Head of Studies to be prepared
Some additional statistics about this group of students. Create a sub / function that can graphs the following i
The sheet "Delayed Students":

- The percentage distribution of late students between each Study Board
- The percentage distribution of late students between each PROGRAM_ID's
- The percentage distribution of late students between each faculty
- The percentage distribution of late students between each campus
- The number of late students distributed by ENROLL_PERIOD

The Head of Studies would like to be able to generate the statistics by pressing a button on the sheet "Delayed Students".

This is my code and it doesn't want to work:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range ("A2: I2")
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source: = rng
cht.Chart.Chartype = xlXYScatterLines
cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Statistic of Student"
```

Comment: Define "doesn't want to work". Is there an error? If so, what is the error message, and on which line does the error occur? If there is no error, then what is the code not doing which it should, or doing which it should not? [Saying 'it doesn't work' isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `rng` and the `cht` as objects. This works:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rng As Object, cht As Object
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2: I2")
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2

    With cht.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Statistic of Student"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this MSDN-page which explains how to create graphs via VBA:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203725(v=office.11).aspx

> Code from their page:

```
Sub AddChartSheet()
        Dim chtChart As Chart
        'Create a new chart.
        Set chtChart = Charts.Add
    With chtChart
          .Name = "Tool Sales2"
       .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
       'Link to the source data range.
       .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D5"), _
         PlotBy:=xlRows
       .HasTitle = True
       .ChartTitle.Text = "=Sheet1!R1C2"
       .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
       .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Month"
       .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
       .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Sales"
   End With
End Sub
```

> ---

So this removes your mistakes:

```
Dim cht As Chart
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range ("A2: I2")
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:= rng, PlotBy:=xlRows
cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Statistic of Student"
```